# React Navigation : Bottom Up Transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, transition, react-navigation

I'm using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) in my react-native project in order to handle my navigation and routes.

In my case, i have a `ViewA` and a `ViewB`.

The `ViewA` needs informations that i'm filling in my `ViewB`.

The userflow is `ViewA` -> `ViewB` -> `ViewA`.

```
** VIEW A **
import React from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

class ViewA extends React.Component {
  state = { selected: false };

  onSelect = data => {
    this.setState(data);
  };

  onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigate("ViewB", { onSelect: this.onSelect });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.selected ? "Selected" : "Not Selected"}</Text>
        <Button title="Next" onPress={this.onPress} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

.

```
**VIEW B**
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";

class ViewB extends React.Component {
  goBack() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.goBack();
    navigation.state.params.onSelect({ selected: true });
  }

  render() {
    return <Button title="back" onPress={this.goBack} />;
  }
}
```

What i'm trying to do is : Instead of opening my `ViewB` from left to right, i'd like it to be opened from bottom to up ('above' the ViewA) and having a close transition 'top-bottom'. Such as a Modal.

My issue is, i want to keep my StackNavigator as it is. And would like to custom this transition.

I don't want a Modal.

Thanks for your time and your help

Comment: Have you looked at the [transitioner](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/views/transitioner) ?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you import this at the top of your page

```
import CardStackStyleInterpolator from "react-navigation/src/views/CardStack/CardStackStyleInterpolator";
```

This is what your navigator should look like for simple transitions.

```
StackNavigator(
 {
   Scenes...
 },
 {
   transitionConfig: () => ({
     screenInterpolator: props => {

       // Basically you need to create a condition for individual scenes
       if (props.scene.route.routeName === 'NameOfOneScene') {

         // forVertical makes the scene transition for Top to Bottom
         return CardStackStyleInterpolator.forVertical(props);
       }

       const last = props.scenes[props.scenes.length - 1];

       // This controls the transition when navigation back toa specific scene
       if (last.route.routeName === 'NameOfOneScene') {

         // Here, forVertical flows from Top to Bottom
         return CardStackStyleInterpolator.forVertical(props);
       }

       This declares the default transition for every other scene
       return CardStackStyleInterpolator.forHorizontal(props);
    },
    navigationOptions: { 
      ... 
    },
    cardStyle: {
      ...
    }
 }
```